# World Space UI on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a "dynamic" worldspace UI which is displaying on the screen when I'm interacting with a few objects, it's going to be images mainly, like this:

[Triangle Button example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcRbs.jpg)

[Triangle Button example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XVCQ.jpg)

I made this (below) but the problem is it depends from the player distance, too far images are small, too close images are huge, I know it's because of the image is an object into a worldspace. But I want to know the right way to make this, just like the example I posted above.

```
void WorldButton()
{
    // canvas in worldspace mode is attached to a gamobject
    worldButton.SetActive(true); 
    Vector3 direction = worldButton.transform.position - cam.transform.position;
    worldButton.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure those use a screen space UI and use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html to place the canvas

Comment: Yeah, you're right, its working right now, I just need to add some lerp to make it smooth, thanks.